# Flaw in this proof that the union of two open sets is open?

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

I'm trying to show that if U, V are open sets of $\mathbb{C}$, then U $\cup$ V is an open set of $\mathbb{C}$.

My attempt at proving this is as follows:

If $U$ is open, $\forall x$ $\in$ U, $\exists$ a ball $B(x, r_1)$ with $r_1 > 0 \subseteq U$

If $V$ is open, $\forall x$ $\in$ V, $\exists$ B(x, r2) with $r_2 > 0 \subseteq V$

So we need to show that for $U \cup V$ to be open, $\forall$ x $\in$ $ U\cup V$, $\exists B(x, r)$ with $r > 0 \subseteq U \cup V$

If we take r = min(r1, r2), then we've guaranteed that the ball B(x, r) must fit in both U and V, so it must be contained within $ U\cup V$, so $ U\cup V$ must be open.

Does this make sense? Or is there a flaw in the logic? It seems a bit simple so I'm not sure if I've made an incorrect assumption somewhere.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Your proof is more suitable to show $U\cap V$ is open. For $U\cup V$, you observe $U\subset U\cup V$ and $V\subset U\cup V$

Comment: $r_1$ and $r_2$ only exist both for $x\in U\cap V$. The verbal argument seems to support that you think of the intersection. If your task is to prove that the intersection of two open sets $U,V$ - $U\cap V$ - is open, the argument is okay. If your task is showing that $U\cup V$, the union of $U$ and $V$ is open, your argument misses the task.

Comment: Note that $r_1$ and $r_2$ depend on $x$ and both exist only if $x\in U\cap V$. Take $r$= either $r_1$ (if $x\in U$) or $r_2$ (if $x\in V$), replace the sentence "$B(x,r)$ must fit in both $U$ and $V$" with "$B(x,r)$ must fit in $U$ or $V$" and then it is ok.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments, and sorry for the poor phrasing, I meant the ball B(x, min(r1, r2)) must fit in the union of U and V, rather than the intersection of U and V.

To explain my thought process better, if you can completely contain a ball around any point in U, and you can do the same for V, then you must be able to construct a ball fully contained around any point in U $\cup$ V by shrinking it's radius to the least possible size, the minimum of the radii of the ball for U and the ball for V.

I will attempt to fix the proof using your recommendations, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comments that your initial proof looks more like proving $U\cap V$ is open.

Suggestion: Choose an arbitrary element $x\in U\cup V$.  Proceed by cases.  Case 1: $x\in U$.  Case 2: $x\in V$

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I agree, my error seems to be my assumption that we can just pick min(r1, r2) regardless of where x lies in $U /cup V$, when really I think I should be saying if $ x \in U, \notin V$, then we can pick r1, if $ x \in V, \notin U$, then we can pick r2, and if $ x \in U, \in V$, then we can pick min(r1, r2).